# Getting sum as at particular timestamp in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have SQL table which has 4 columns like this

```html
entry_time          |  A        | B      |
-------------------------------------------
2015-06-05 18:44:56 |  10       |  8     |
2015-06-06 16:04:36 |  -5       | -2     |
2015-06-07 10:01:14 |   3       |  1     |
```

I want to get the sum of A and B columns up to particular given time stamp like below.

```html
 status at given date |  A        | B      |
 -------------------------------------------
 2015-06-05 23:59:59 |  10       |  8     |
 2015-06-06 23:59:59 |   5       |  6     |
 2015-06-07 23:59:59 |   8       |  7     |
```

I thought using of between. But as I am giving the date I want totals from front end without seeing of data table and its first records date, is there any way to solve this.Please help me.

Comment: You mean sum for a day?

Comment: not a day actually. I want  sum up to that specific date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using user defined variable in mysql, however this needs ordering for deciding the data and I am assuming that timestamp value defines the ordering here. So using the following you can get the desired result

```
select
entry_time,
a_sum as A,
b_sum as B from(
  select 
  entry_time,
  @A_sum:= @A_sum + A as a_sum,
  @B_sum:= @B_sum + B as b_sum
  from table_name,(select @A_sum:=0,@B_sum:=0)x
  order by entry_time
)x
```

Comment: Don't you think using desired alias names in the inner query is just suffice and outer query is not necessary !?

Comment: Actually it is the outer query is not needed :)

Comment: Can you suggest a way if i need those totals for one time stamp and don't need it for all entries in SQL table. Probably the time stamp I am going to use is not in the table, what should I do if I need sum of data before that time stamp

Comment: Please provide some sample example of what you are looking at.

Comment: If I want the totals only for a single timestamp such as  2015-06-06 23:59:59 |   5       |  6     | what should I do

Comment: Just add a where condition at the end as `where entry_time = '2015-06-06 23:59:59' `